# Bootstrap dropdown with PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a really big system for my YouTube network and I am kind of confused with why my bootstrap dropdown doesn't work. It worked all fine until I put the PHP code in it to check if the user is logged in.

Here's my code:

```
 <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
?>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bgtracker Group | Home</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bgtracker Group</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">General Links</li>
                            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="partner.php">Become a partner</a></li>
                            <li><a href="recruiter.php">Become a recruiter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="network.php">Become a network</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">System Links</li>
                            <?php
                            $user = new user();
                            if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
                                echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Log-in</a></li>";
                            } else if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
                                echo "<li><a href='update.php'>Update Profile</a></li>";
                                echo "<li><a href='changepassword.php'>Change Password</a></li>";
                                echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Log-out</a></li>";
                            }
                            if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
                                if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
                                echo "<li><a href='#'>|</a></li>";
                                echo "<li><a href='admin.php'>Admin CP</a></li>";
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1>
                    <?php
                    if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
                        echo "Welcome, ";
                        echo escape($user->data()->username);
                        echo "!";
                    } else if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
                        echo "Welcome, guest!";
                    }


                    //YouTube Stats


                    ?>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is that file `.php` or able to be treated as PHP?

Comment: Yes. The file is a .php.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: No errors are shown in my php code. It seems to be all fine.

Comment: Did you try interchangeing " and ' quotes? So that you have for instance:
`echo '<li><a href="admin.php">Admin CP</a></li>';`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it myself. It was the 'return false' statement. It was somehow returning false on my code and thus not displaying anything. I put it there with the mindset that if the user is not logged in it will just not display anything but oh well.